# AWS API Gateway CORS from Swagger

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors, swagger, api-gateway

I am importing a Swagger file into a Terraform created AWS API Gateway deployment, and everything seems to work fine apart from enabling CORS. Once I have finished deploying, then I always receive the 403 CORS error from any endpoint. I have to manually then go through an enable CORS within the AWS console.

I import the swagger file via the AWS CLI like this;

```
aws apigateway put-rest-api \
    --body file://swagger.json \
    --mode overwrite \
    --rest-api-id ${REST_API_ID}
```

The swagger file uses the below to map the correct headers;

```
"x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
   "responses": {
      "2\\d{2}": {
          "statusCode": "200",
          "responseParameters": {
              "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,X-Correlation-ID'",
              "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods" : "'*'",
              "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "'*'"
           }
       }
    }
}
```

This maps to response codes within the top level Swagger file;

```
"responses": {
    "200": {
         "description": "Succesfully created Report",
         "headers": {
             "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": {
                 "type": "string"
              },
              "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": {
                 "type": "string"
              },
              "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": {
                  "type": "string"
              }
          }                        
     }
}
```

Despite doing this, I still get CORS erros straight after importing the Swagger file.

Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: Where you able to resolve this issue ? if yes can you please post the solution.